# Common diagnostics which VisualVM is used for

Tags: java, profiling, heap

There's a lot of documentation out there on how to *use* the 'jvisualvm' profiler, but very little (if any) real-life advice on how to *analyze* all those charts and dumps. I'm just a little overwhelmed by all the graphs and having trouble making sense of it all.

I know this is sort of a monolithic-type question, but there *has* to be a way to condense its *typical* uses into a fairly concise list - finding memory leaks, zombie threads and such.

What specifically are  some of the common analyses for VisualVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What specifically are some of the common analyses for VisualVM?

I think these are the same as for any other Java profiler. For example, [YourKit profiler demos](http://www.yourkit.com/docs/index.jsp) page currently lists the following "most popular" analyses:

- CPU profiling
- J2EE profiling
- Finding a memory leak
- Profiling excessive garbage allocations